# Intuitively, why is compounding percentages not expressed as adding percentages?

Tags: intuition, percentages

I pursue only intuition; please do not answer with formal proofs. I already know the theoretical reason: because  each percentage expresses a different base. $1.$ But why not intuitively?

My problem: Whenever adding percentages, I am always initially tempted to add them as cardinal numbers, before resisting myself and spending $\geq 5$  minutes recollecting the following algebra and surmounting the temptation, all of which reveal chasms in  my comprehension.

$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid gray]{ \text{ Optional Reading and Supplement: } }$

If the price of apricots ($a$) increases by $p_a$  and the price of cherries ($c$) increases by $p_c$, where $0 \le p_a,p_c \leq 1$; then the $\color{green}{ \text {Correct new price =}    (1 + p_a)a + (1 + p_c)c. \tag{2}}$
But adding the percentages as cardinal numbers produces the: $\color{darkred}{ \text { Incorrect new price =}    (1 + p_a + p_c)( a + c) = \color{green}{(1 + p_a)a + (1 + p_c)c} \color{#FF4F00}{ + p_ac + p_ca.} \tag{3}}$

The existence of the 2 orange terms proves $2 \neq 3$, but do not reveal the intuition.
<sub>PS: This question is motivated by [the first sentence of this quote in this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/31392/8572).</sub>

Comment: I do not get this. A percentage is $p/100$ expressed as $p \%$. Such fractions can be added.

Comment: @mvw Sorry for any poor writing. I was trying to generalise [this](http://www.nettakeaway.com/tp/article/320/adding-percentages-youre-wrong): 'So, the classic case: You have a 20% off coupon, and the item is marked off 25% from regular price. What’s your actual savings at the register? Most people immediately add 20% and 25% and arrive at 45% off, immediately running to the register.'

Comment: Maybe it helps to think of an extreme case where apricots cost 100 dollars each and cherries cost 1 cent each.  The price of apricots increases by 1 percent (thankfully, a small increase) and the price of cherries increases by 500 percent (large, but still insignificant because cherries are very cheap).  So how much does it cost now for an apricot and a cherry?  If you add the percentages you'll get a huge price, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Where did  you find the example with price $a$ for apricots and $c$ for cherries? There seems to be something wrong there, either with the choice of words or with the entire idea of the exercise. Did you copy it from a book, and are you sure you copied it accurately? (In any case, the apricots and cherries example has nothing to do with what happens when two percentage discounts are applied to the _same_ item.)

Comment: @DavidK Sorry for any confusion; I constructed the example above, but I based it on the fallacy in the link.

Comment: The fallacy in the link is actually a much worse error than the mistake people sometimes make in trying to compute the result of two discounts applied to the same item. Adding the percentages of two discounts is at least _approximately_ correct when the percentages are small; the example in the link represents an error that is several times larger than the percentages involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on the premise that the motivation behind
the question is to explain the fallacy described
[in this question on philosophy.SE.](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31392/if-everything-had-increased-by-20-this-would-justify-only-20-in-the-price-o)

One point of confusion is the use of the word *price.*
In general, when we must spend money on several resources (flour, labor, utilities, and rent) to make a loaf of bread, the price of a loaf is
not determined by the prices of the resources used in its production.
Rather, it is determined by the *cost* of those resources,
which is determined by both the price of each resource and the
quantity of each resource consumed in making the loaf.

For example, if rent is $\$2000$ per month, that does not mean the
baker must charge more than $\$2000$ for one loaf in order to make a profit.
Rather, if the bakery produces $10000$ loaves each month, the baker could
accurately say that each loaf cost $\$0.20$ of rent to produce,
in addition to other costs.

So, assuming the only things the baker has to pay for are for flour, labor, utilities, and rent, the baker's cost to make a loaf of bread is

$$ B = F \cdot Q_F + L \cdot Q_L + U \cdot Q_U + R \cdot Q_R, $$

where $F$, $L$, $U$, and $R$ are the *prices* of flour, labor, utilities, and rent, and $Q_F$, $Q_L$, $Q_U$, and $Q_R$ are the *quantities* of
each of those resources that the baker has to expend on each loaf.

Now, assuming the amount of each resource per loaf remains constant,
it is true that a $10$ percent increase in the *price* of one resource
corresponds to a $10$ percent increase in the *cost* of that resource.
For example, if the price of flour goes up $10$ percent, from $F$ to
$(1 + 0.10)F$, the cost of flour per loaf also increases $10$ percent,
because
$$ ((1 + 0.10)F) \cdot Q_F = (1 + 0.10)(F \cdot Q_F). $$

Of course, if we just *say* "cost" instead of *price* when describing
the baker's expenses, we bypass all of these complications. So let's do that.

What happens, then, when the *costs* of all these items increase?
The baker was writing checks to four different groups of people before
-- the flour merchants, his laborers, the utility companies, and his landlord -- and he is still writing checks to the same four groups of people.
The amount of each group of checks has merely increased.
So if the baker was paying $\$600$ to the flour merchants each month before,
and flour goes up $10$ percent, now he must pay the flour merchants
$\$660$ each month.
If the baker was previously paying his laborers a total of
$\$5000$ per month, and labor rates increase $20$ percent,
he must now pay his laborers $\$6000$ per month.
That is, for flour and labor, the new costs add up to

$$ (1 + 0.10) 600 + (1 + 0.20) 5000, $$

which are analogous to the terms $(1 + p_a)a + (1 + p_c)c$
if we say that $a$ and $c$ were the previous
total costs of apricots and cherries
we bought, rather than their unit prices.
Similarly, if utilities and rent were $\$200$ and $\$2000$, respectively,
and these go up $10$ percent each, the baker's total costs after
all these increases are

\begin{align}
 (1 + 0.10) 600 + (1 + 0.20) 5000 + (1 + 0.10) 200 + (1 &+ 0.10) 2000 \\
&= 660 + 6000 + 220 + 2200 \\
&= 9080.
\end{align}

*There are no other added costs.* When we say labor increased $20$ percent,
that $20$ percent accounts for *all* of the extra money the baker must
pay his laborers, and likewise the percentage increases in each other cost
account for *all* the extra money the baker must pay each of the other
three groups of people.

Given all of that, what would it mean to take the $10$-percent increase
in flour and multiply it by the cost of labor? This would be
$0.10 \cdot \$5000 = \$500$ in our example; but to whom does the
baker pay this extra $\$500$?

If each of the baker's costs *individually* had gone up $50$ percent,
then indeed his cost per loaf would also have increased $50$ percent.
Here's how. Before the increase, the baker's total costs were

$$ 600 + 5000 + 200 + 2000 = 7800.$$

That's $\$0.78$ per loaf (since the bakery produces $10000$ loaves).
After $50$-percent increases in flour, labor, utilities, and rent,
all occurring in the same month, the baker's costs would be

$$ 900 + 7500 + 300 + 3000 = 11700,$$

which is $1.17$ per loaf, which is indeed a $50$-percent increase.
But of course that's not what happened at all, and the baker
either is not paying attention to his own accounts 
(or is trying to fool us) when he says it *is* what happened.

Answer (score 3):

Say something costs $\$100$ and the price goes up by $50\%$.

$50\%$ of $\$100$ is $\$50$, so the new price is $\$150$.

Then it goes up by $50\%$ again.

$50\%$ of $\$150$ is $\$75$, so the new price is $\$225$.

The point is that the second time, you're taking $50\%$ of a larger quantity.

Answer (score 0):

> So, the classic case: You have a 20% off coupon, and the item is
>   marked off 25% from regular price. What’s your actual savings at the
>   register? Most people immediately add 20% and 25% and arrive at 45%
>   off, immediately running to the register.

The absolute saving is $p_1 P_1+p_2 P_2$, the new percentage is
$$
p = \frac{p_1 P_1 + p_2 P_2}{P_1 + P_2}
$$
if the prices were the same $P_1=P_2=P$ the absolute saving would be $(p_1 +p_2)P$ and the percentage
$$
p = \frac{p_1 P + p_2 P}{P + P} = \frac{p_1+p_2}{2}
$$ 
which is the average of the two old percentages.

For other problems we might end up with different relationships between absolute savings and saving in percent. The problem by Michael Hardy, which is iterated prices increases is such a problem.

If you add $20\%$ and $30\%$ of a pizza slice, you talk about $50\%$ of the pizza, so in this context they add.

In summary: You can not expect an additive behaviour of percentages over many different problems, just because some involved quantities are expressed as percentages.